# How to implement Hot module Replacement in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular9, ng-build, hot-module-replacement

I am working on a big project and it takes to much time to run that project, so while googling I got an idea of hot module replacement, but I don't know how to implement it so please help me how to implement HRM in angular 9

Answer (score -1):

It is not a part of angular 9, it is released with Angular 11 by default. You should upgrade the angular version and ready to use it.

Main reason: Earlier even making a smaller change trigger angular dev server to re-compile and process all the files again which takes time to re-render and re-paint everything with HMR it will be quick. It takes a lot of time based on your system configuration.

`HMR is not a angular feature, but it is a webpack feature` and bundled in the angular 11 version by default. HMR is to update the application modules without reloading and repainting everything.

How to use it:

```
ng serve --hmr
```

You can check [here](https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-11-hot-module-replacement/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20HMR%20feature%20in,the%20changes%20in%20the%20project.) for more details.

Comment: If the answer helps , you can accept and upvote it. You will be rewarded for that too!